# How can I load tsv file of node server using D3 in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, d3.js

I have practiced visualization of data using AngularJS, D3.js and node.js.

My Application structure is below.

```
Application/
  client/
    app/
      app.js
      index.html
      dashboard/
        dashboard.html
        dashboard.js
        dashboard.controller.js
        dashboard.service.js
      main/
  server/
      server.js
      api/
      data/
        data.tsv
```

I want to load `data.tsv` of server using dashboard controller. However, it showed just `404 Not Found`.

dashboard.controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('Dashboard')
        .controller('DashboardCtrl', DashboardCtrl);

    function DashboardCtrl($scope, d3) {
        d3.tsv("/data/data.tsv", function(data) {
            console.log(data[0])
        });
    }
})();
```

sever.js

```
app.post('/data', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./data/result.tsv', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }else {
            res.write(data);
            console.log('written!');
        }
    });
});
```

Then, how can I load tsv file in server?

Comment: perhaps it should be `app.get` instead of `app.post`. AFAIK `d3.tsv` will send GET request. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: It seems that the request method is not error.

Comment: maybe you can try this line: `app.use('/data', express.static(__dirname + '/data'))`

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
fs.readFile("data/result.tsv", "utf8", function(error, data) { 
  data = d3.tsv.parse(data);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```